How to edit VSCODE's setting.json when using remote mode?
I am using vscode on Mac to open remote jupyter notebook on Ubuntu.
I want to add functions to setting.json.
when I open

setting.json

on vscode, it is read-only.
Where is the setting.json? I cannot find it in the remote folder

To edit settings.json in VS Code remote mode:
Open VS Code in Remote Mode via Remote - SSH or Remote - Containers.
Press Cmd + Shift + P (Mac) or Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux),
then select Preferences: Open Settings (JSON).
Edit the remote settings.json file to adjust configurations.
Save changes with Cmd + S or Ctrl + S.
